# SQL compact edition? Or an alternative

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio

I'am building an application, which need to only record it's settings trough a database, so like I logged in with the name: "Mobstaa", it needs to fill the username textbox the next time I start up the application. There are a few other little settings like that, that needs to be stored in that Database.

Now I'am wondering if it is smart to use SQL Compact Edition, I read about a few disadventages of the compact edition, but I really don't want the users that will run my application need to install a very big SQL file for just a small application, does anybody know wether it is smart for me to use the SQL Compact Edition, or does anybody has a very good alternative for my problem?

Comment: if there are only a few settings use an xml config file (or .ini file, but preferably the former)....

Comment: use Sqlite, just one dll and EF support.

Comment: What's the schema of your database going to be? If it's simply key-value store of settings you really don't need a database.

Comment: I'am already sort of working with the normal SQL server from Microsoft, there is a lot done there, so I don' t want to return to something like XMl, because I'am already using a lot of query's, one more question: does SQLite support Rollback transactions?

Comment: @Mobstaa yes, ROLLBACK is possible, reference this link: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want only to store some settings and want to use a Database, i would suggest that you use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).  This db is much more lightweight than MS-SQL Compact Edition and it's an in-memory database, so you can ship the db within your product and don't have to install a seperate database on your computer.

Comment: I like that idea, does at have any disadventages? And do you have a good tutorial about it?

Comment: For your prerequisites i don't think there are much disadvantages if the DB doesn't get MUCH complexer. And if you decide to store more than just settings you can easily expand the database.

Comment: Security is a big disadvantage. As far as I can see there is no comprehensive way to secure SqlLite, not easily anyway. I am prepared to be challenged as if there is I'll switch